pipx can't use globally installed truststore package
I would like to start using pipx in a corporate Windows environment where TLS interception is used. My first goal with it is to install poetry. I have pip set up here and working perfectly fine thanks to using the truststore Python package. But when I try to run the command pipx install poetry from inside an elevated command prompt I get the following error message:
C:\WINDOWS\system32>python -m pipx install poetry
Fatal error from pip prevented installation. Full pip output in file:
    C:\Users\joshua\pipx\logs\cmd_2024-07-24_15.44.36_pip_errors.log

Some possibly relevant errors from pip install:
    ERROR: To use the truststore feature, 'truststore' must be installed into pip's current environment.

Error installing poetry.

Running python -m pip list in the same session confirms that truststore is installed globally and should be available to pipx. So what I am missing here? How do I get pipx to detect and use truststore/how do I fix this issue?
I could not find anything using Google or on this site about this error. Thank you in advance for your input!
